# Sigtrap crash in Webcore

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebView in my iOS application and I keep getting a random crash a few times a day that I see on Flurry. I have no steps to reproduce it.

I would appreciate any ideas on how can I proceed further with this.

Here is the crash log I am seeing.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad5,3
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x184391688
Crashed Thread:  3

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966cce0c _mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                      0x18446b724 <redacted> + 200
2   CoreFoundation                      0x184469678 <redacted> + 940
3   CoreFoundation                      0x1843952d4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
4   GraphicsServices                    0x18dcb36fc _GSEventRunModal + 168
5   UIKit                               0x188f92f40 _UIApplicationMain + 1488
6   <APPLICATION>                             0x10007d2f4 -[<APPLICATION>ProgramViewController .cxx_destruct] + 112
7   libdyld.dylib                       0x1965cea08 <redacted> + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966ccc24 _kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x1965a399c <redacted> + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966cce0c _mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                      0x18446b724 <redacted> + 200
2   CoreFoundation                      0x184469678 <redacted> + 940
3   CoreFoundation                      0x1843952d4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
4   CFNetwork                           0x183e72594 <redacted> + 440
5   Foundation                          0x1853b5db8 <redacted> + 1072
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x184391688 _CFRelease + 1084
1   WebCore                             0x192f129c4 <redacted> + 48
2   WebCore                             0x192e78ef4 <redacted> + 36
3   CoreFoundation                      0x18446c12c <redacted> + 28
4   CoreFoundation                      0x18446bddc <redacted> + 888
5   CoreFoundation                      0x184469828 <redacted> + 1372
6   CoreFoundation                      0x1843952d4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
7   WebCore                             0x192f002e4 <redacted> + 468
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7078 ___psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                      0x1956a0d60 __ZNSt3__118condition_variable15__do_timed_waitERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEENS_6chrono10time_pointINS5_12system_clockENS5_8durationIxNS_5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEEEEE + 140
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x185af2578 <redacted> + 180
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x18598958c <redacted> + 80
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x185984ba0 <redacted> + 24
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7078 ___psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                      0x1956a0cb0 __ZNSt3__118condition_variable4waitERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEE + 56
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x185c32ee0 <redacted> + 156
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x185c32f84 <redacted> + 92
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x185984ba0 <redacted> + 24
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7078 ___psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                      0x1956a0cb0 __ZNSt3__118condition_variable4waitERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEE + 56
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x185c32ee0 <redacted> + 156
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x185c32f84 <redacted> + 92
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x185984ba0 <redacted> + 24
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7498 ___select + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966cce0c _mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                      0x18446b724 <redacted> + 200
2   CoreFoundation                      0x184469678 <redacted> + 940
3   CoreFoundation                      0x1843952d4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
4   WebCore                             0x192f344f0 <redacted> + 288
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x185984ba0 <redacted> + 24
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966cce0c _mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                      0x18446b724 <redacted> + 200
2   CoreFoundation                      0x184469678 <redacted> + 940
3   CoreFoundation                      0x1843952d4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
4   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x182e09024 <redacted> + 164
5   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x182dfba04 <redacted> + 120
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966cce48 _semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   MediaToolbox                        0x1869c88fc <redacted> + 1956
2   CoreMedia                           0x184ccf8f4 <redacted> + 248
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966cce48 _semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   MediaToolbox                        0x1869c88fc <redacted> + 1956
2   CoreMedia                           0x184ccf8f4 <redacted> + 248
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966cce0c _mach_msg_trap + 8
1   MediaToolbox                        0x1869d0610 <redacted> + 104
2   CoreMedia                           0x184ccf8f4 <redacted> + 248
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966cce48 _semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   MediaToolbox                        0x1869c88fc <redacted> + 1956
2   CoreMedia                           0x184ccf8f4 <redacted> + 248
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783dc8 <redacted> + 164
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196783d24 <redacted> + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef8 _thread_start + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7c78 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef0 _start_wqthread + 4

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7c78 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef0 _start_wqthread + 4

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7c78 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef0 _start_wqthread + 4

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7c78 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef0 _start_wqthread + 4

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7c78 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef0 _start_wqthread + 4

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1966e7c78 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x196780ef0 _start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Crash looks like it is in CFRelease which might indicate nil was passed to it. Starting point you need is the full stack trace without the <redacted> entries so you can see what was being called to figure out what might be happening. Quite a few articles on SO on this.